# Can EOS assure privacy?

Tags: eosio-code, privacy

In ethereum (public network), the data is all open access. Functions can be controlled via function modifiers. But anyone can view data stored in the contract.

Is this the same in EOS? Once data is stored in an EOS contract, is that then always accessible to anyone? (I assume here a public network is used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data stored in a contract is public. Natively, EOSIO cannot assure privacy and there are currently no official public plans to change this. However, to preserve privacy, one may just store data that was previously encrypted.

[This question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/q/2598/961) offers a similar discussion, and [this question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/q/2343/961) discusses ways to encrypt data before storing it on the chain.